# jquery adding input val together

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason my code returns "0111" when the returned value should be 3 adding the numbers together.

Is there a better way to write this so it adds the value of the input text?

```
var p = $(".p").val(); 
var r = $(".r").val();
var d = $(".d").val();
var s = $(".s").val();

var checkability = p + r + d + s;

alert(checkability)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are concatenating strings you need to cast it to numeric. `val()` return data as string, or explicitly use `parseInt(var, 10)` or `parseFloat` based on your type.

Simple way is t use [unary + operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) prefixing the variable:

```
var checkability = +p + +r + +d + +s;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YkC6M/)**

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the easiest thing is to coerce the string values into integers like:

```
var p = +$(".p").val(); 
var r = +$(".r").val();
var d = +$(".d").val();
var s = +$(".s").val();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jhVJ5/)**

You could also use the longer `parseInt()` function like `var p = parseInt( $(".p").val(), 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt to make them integers

```
var p = parseInt($(".p").val(),10); 
var r = parseInt($(".r").val(),10);
var d = parseInt($(".d").val(),10);
var s = parseInt($(".s").val(),10);

var checkability = p + r + d + s;

alert(checkability)
```

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` without a radix, doubly so if you are dealing with user input.

Comment: @Quentin What if you want to support user input of both hex and dec? :)

Comment: @BarbaraLaird — Then that is best handled with a clear, radio button based, user interface :)